# Character Comparision

Tags: c

I am trying to compare words in letter in C.

My code is:

```
char kel[100];
char check[7];

check is random 8 letter

printf("Please Enter the Word:");
    scanf("%s", &kel); 



for(int k = 0; k < 7; k++) 
     {
         for(int j = 0; j < size; j++)
         {
             if(check[i] != kel[i])
             {
                  printf("Different");   
             }
         }
     }
```

I want to check random letter in kel words. If random letter do not include in kel I want to give warning.

How can I do that?

Thanks,
John

Comment: It's not very clear what you want to do, I'm afraid. Also, the `if` probably should use the loop indices `k` and `j`, not the un-defined `i`. No way you compiled that.

Comment: remove `&` in `scanf("%s",&kel);` change to `scanf("%s",kel);` that the way to do it... so what's the problem you are facing?

Comment: why don't you just use `strstr`?

Comment: I am trying to make scrabble in C.

Comment: and I want to check the letters in word which is using in word or not.

Comment: if(check[i] != kel[i]) should be if(check[k] != kel[j]).some of your problems may be solved.Try to get the value of size using function strlen.

Comment: @John you said you need 8 letters but only declared `check`  for 7 letters

Answer (score 0):

maybe

```
#include <string.h>

if(NULL==strpbrk(kel, check)){
    printf("not include");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int size = strlen(kel);

for(int k = 0; k < 8; k++) 
{
    int j;

    for(j = 0; j < size; j++)
    {
        if(check[k] == kel[j])
        {
            break;
        }
     }

     if(j == size)
         printf("Warning: different!");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use magic numbers, hope this helps

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAX 7

int main(void)
{
    char kel[100] = {0};
    char check[MAX];
    int i, j;

    printf("Please Enter the Word:");
    scanf("%s", kel); /* You don't need &, kel is already a pointer */
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
    printf("Your random is:");
    for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        check[i] = 31 + rand() % 96; /* This will give you printable ASCIIs */
        putchar(check[i]);
    }
    putchar('\n');
    for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < MAX; j++) {
            if (check[i] == kel[j]) break;
        }
        if (j == MAX) printf("Different %c\n", check[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Don't use magic numbers", and you post code using 4 magic numbers.

Comment: @rubenvb, you're right, well ... only 3, `0` can not be considered a magic number :P

Comment: You've got a `7`, a `100`, a `32` and a `96`. All magic. Though I suppose in C it'd be difficult to get rid of an explicit buffer size.